# Create a java zip FileSystem from an encrypted zip

Tags: java, android, encryption, filesystems, zip

I discovered that Java 7 introduced a zip FileSystem. Currently I have a encrypted zip files, that  I'm decrypting with the following code

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
Crypto algo = new Crypto();
algo.initV1();
in = new CipherInputStream(in, algo.getCiphertoDec(in, pass));
ZipInputStream zipInput = new ZipInputStream(in);
ZipEntry ze = zipInput.getNextEntry();
....
```

and the method getCiphertoDec is like this

```
public Cipher getCiphertoDec (InputStream in, String password) throws Exception {
    byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_SIZE_BYTE];
    if (in.read(salt) < SALT_SIZE_BYTE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file length (needs a full block for salt)");
    };

    key = CoreCryptoV1.PBKDF2.pbkdf2(password, salt, 1000);

    ivBytes = new byte[IV_LENGTH_BYTE];
    if (in.read(ivBytes) < IV_LENGTH_BYTE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file length (needs a full block for iv)");
    };

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
    return cipher;
}
```

I wonder if there is any way to treat encrypted zip file as a file system.
I appreciate any advice.
I would like a solution that is compatible with android.

Comment: Given that your decryption method is customized, I doubt it. You could always decrypt the stream to a file on disk and then use the zip `FileSystem` on top of that, but I suspect that defeats whatever reason you had for keeping the zip file encrypted to begin with.

Comment: @Dan is a rare that zip File System can not be created from an InputStream, that would solve my problem