# creating a java.nio.file.FileSystem from a .zip file if it's encrypted?

Tags: java, encryption, zip, nio2

There's a relatively new [zip filesystem provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) that's a supported part of the NIO2 library in JDK7 and above.

I specifically need it to support the [java.nio.file.FileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) class.

Is it compatible with encrypted .zip files and if so, how do you specify a decryption key?

---

very similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096004/create-a-java-zip-filesystem-from-an-encrypted-zip) but it's on Android; I don't need to worry about Android in my case, or support any existing code.

Comment: May I humbly recommend the [Apache VFS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) package?

Comment: re: Apache VFS: it looks very interesting, but I need it to `support java.nio.file.Filesystem`, and it looks like VFS does not; I guess Apache did their own thing before NIO2.

Answer (score 2):

If you trie to mount an encrypted zip file you get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipError: invalid CEN header (encrypted entry)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.zerror(ZipFileSystem.java:1605)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.initCEN(ZipFileSystem.java:1064)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.<init>(ZipFileSystem.java:130)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:139)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:390)
```

The causing line is

```
if ((ZipConstants.CENFLG(arrayOfByte1, i) & 0x1) != 0)
    zerror("invalid CEN header (encrypted entry)");
```

So the exception is thrown for every encrypted entry. Therefore the ZipFileSystem does not support encrypted files at the moment (Java 8).